# iOS:Navigation bar not showing when is embed from the main view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following layout on my story board:

[image]

When I click on the button I load the blue view controller:

```
- (IBAction)blue:(id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    BlueViewController *blue = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BlueViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:blue animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The blue view controller has navigation bar embed. But doesn't show on either the blue viewcontoller or the pink view contoller:

[image]
My question to you guys is what I'm doing wrong? or why does the view controller is not showing ?

Answer (score 2):

Give the navigation controller for blue VC a storyboard ID, and present that instead of blue VC.

If you present a VC, even though it has a navigation controler it doesnt show up as you present only the view cotroller.

```
- (IBAction)blue:(id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *blueNavVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BlueViewControllerNavigationController"];
    [self presentViewController: blueNavVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And when you want to move from blue to pink, you need to push to pink controller as pink is part of the blue navigation controller stack!

Comment: What you mean?, can you post an example?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present on a view controller then you have to add a custom view in in top of your controller cz it's on the your navigation controller. If you push a controller then you don't need the above. You will find the same navigationbar to all. Cz It's within your navigation controller stack.